# Oracle - Increment value

Tags: oracle11g, increment, analytic-functions

I have a table holding customer invoice data.  I am trying to find how many consequently months a particular transaction type is present on a customer’s invoice by creating a carryover counter. If the transaction is no longer present, the counter should reset to zero.

Table:

```
+------------+-------------+----------------+----------+
| Invoice_Id | Customer_id | Transaction_id | Sequence |
+------------+-------------+----------------+----------+
|     253442 |       23334 |                |        1 |
|     253443 |       23334 |                |        2 |
|     253444 |       23334 |                |        3 |
|     253445 |       23334 |                |        4 |
|    1050646 |       23334 |                |        5 |
|    8457065 |       23334 |                |        6 |
|    9052920 |       23334 |                |        7 |
|    9333044 |       23334 |                |        8 |
|    9616743 |       23334 |                |        9 |
|    9894491 |       23334 |                |       10 |
|   10186697 |       23334 |                |       11 |
|   10490938 |       23334 |                |       12 |
|   10803986 |       23334 |       69709477 |       13 |
|   11132317 |       23334 |       72103163 |       14 |
|   11444923 |       23334 |                |       15 |
+------------+-------------+----------------+----------+
```

What I am trying to achieve:

```
+------------+-------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
| Invoice_Id | Customer_id | Transaction_id | Sequence | Carryover |
+------------+-------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
|     253442 |       23334 |                |        1 |         0 |
|     253443 |       23334 |                |        2 |         0 |
|     253444 |       23334 |                |        3 |         0 |
|     253445 |       23334 |                |        4 |         0 |
|    1050646 |       23334 |                |        5 |         0 |
|    8457065 |       23334 |                |        6 |         0 |
|    9052920 |       23334 |                |        7 |         0 |
|    9333044 |       23334 |                |        8 |         0 |
|    9616743 |       23334 |                |        9 |         0 |
|    9894491 |       23334 |                |       10 |         0 |
|   10186697 |       23334 |                |       11 |         0 |
|   10490938 |       23334 |                |       12 |         0 |
|   10803986 |       23334 |       69709477 |       13 |         1 |
|   11132317 |       23334 |       72103163 |       14 |         2 |
|   11444923 |       23334 |                |       15 |         0 |
+------------+-------------+----------------+----------+-----------+
```

I assume I can use analytic functions / Oracle cte?

Thanks!

**add:**

Cumulative sum of transaction_count with reset when transaction_count = 0.

```
+------------+-------------+-------------------+----------+-----------+
| Invoice_Id | Customer_id | Transaction_Count | Sequence | Carryover |
+------------+-------------+-------------------+----------+-----------+
|     253442 |       23334 |                 0 |        1 |         0 |
|     253443 |       23334 |                 0 |        2 |         0 |
|     253444 |       23334 |                 1 |        3 |         1 |
|     253445 |       23334 |                 1 |        4 |         2 |
|    1050646 |       23334 |                 0 |        5 |         0 |
|    8457065 |       23334 |                 0 |        6 |         0 |
|    9052920 |       23334 |                 2 |        7 |         2 |
|    9333044 |       23334 |                 1 |        8 |         3 |
|    9616743 |       23334 |                 0 |        9 |         0 |
|    9894491 |       23334 |                 0 |       10 |         0 |
|   10186697 |       23334 |                 0 |       11 |         0 |
|   10490938 |       23334 |                 0 |       12 |         0 |
|   10803986 |       23334 |                 1 |       13 |         1 |
|   11132317 |       23334 |                 1 |       14 |         2 |
|   11444923 |       23334 |                 0 |       15 |         0 |
+------------+-------------+-------------------+----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand your requirement correctly, here's one way, which uses the [Tabibitosan method](http://rwijk.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/tabibitosan.html) to "group" the data based on onsecutive null / not-null transaction_ids. Once we have that information, we can then do a conditional row_number() based on whether the transaction_id is null or not.

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 253442 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, NULL Transaction_id, 1 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 253443 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, NULL Transaction_id, 2 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 253444 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, NULL Transaction_id, 3 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 253445 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, 123 Transaction_id, 4 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 1050646 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, 456 Transaction_id, 5 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 8457065 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, 789 Transaction_id, 6 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 9052920 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, NULL Transaction_id, 7 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 9333044 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, NULL Transaction_id, 8 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 9616743 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, NULL Transaction_id, 9 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 9894491 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, NULL Transaction_id, 10 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 10186697 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, NULL Transaction_id, 11 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 10490938 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, NULL Transaction_id, 12 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 10803986 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, 69709477 Transaction_id, 13 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 11132317 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, 72103163 Transaction_id, 14 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 11444923 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, NULL Transaction_id, 15 seq FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking your data in a "table" called sample_data
-- you wouldn't need this - you'd just select from your table directly in the sql below:
SELECT invoice_id,
       customer_id,
       transaction_id,
       seq,
       CASE WHEN transaction_id is not NULL THEN
                 row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id, grp ORDER BY seq)
            ELSE 0
       END carryover
FROM   (SELECT invoice_id,
               customer_id,
               transaction_id,
               seq,
               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY seq)
                 - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id, CASE WHEN transaction_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ORDER BY seq) grp
        FROM   sample_data)
ORDER BY customer_id, seq;

INVOICE_ID CUSTOMER_ID TRANSACTION_ID        SEQ  CARRYOVER
---------- ----------- -------------- ---------- ----------
    253442       23334                         1          0
    253443       23334                         2          0
    253444       23334                         3          0
    253445       23334            123          4          1
   1050646       23334            456          5          2
   8457065       23334            789          6          3
   9052920       23334                         7          0
   9333044       23334                         8          0
   9616743       23334                         9          0
   9894491       23334                        10          0
  10186697       23334                        11          0
  10490938       23334                        12          0
  10803986       23334       69709477         13          1
  11132317       23334       72103163         14          2
  11444923       23334                        15          0
```

---

For the additional requirement:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 253442 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, 0 Transaction_Count, 1 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 253443 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, 0 Transaction_Count, 2 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 253444 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, 1 Transaction_Count, 3 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 253445 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, 1 Transaction_Count, 4 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 1050646 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, 0 Transaction_Count, 5 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 8457065 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, 0 Transaction_Count, 6 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 9052920 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, 2 Transaction_Count, 7 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 9333044 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, 1 Transaction_Count, 8 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 9616743 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, 0 Transaction_Count, 9 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 9894491 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, 0 Transaction_Count, 10 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 10186697 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, 0 Transaction_Count, 11 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 10490938 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, 0 Transaction_Count, 12 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 10803986 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, 1 Transaction_Count, 13 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 11132317 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, 1 Transaction_Count, 14 seq FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 11444923 Invoice_Id, 23334 Customer_id, 0 Transaction_Count, 15 seq FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking your data in a "table" called sample_data
-- you wouldn't need this - you'd just select from your table directly in the sql below:
SELECT invoice_id,
       customer_id,
       Transaction_Count,
       seq,
       SUM(transaction_count) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id,
                                                 CASE WHEN Transaction_Count = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
                                                 grp
                                    ORDER BY seq) carryover
FROM   (SELECT invoice_id,
               customer_id,
               Transaction_Count,
               seq,
               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id
                                  ORDER BY seq)
                 - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id,
                                                   CASE WHEN Transaction_Count = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                                      ORDER BY seq) grp
        FROM   sample_data)
ORDER BY customer_id, seq;

INVOICE_ID CUSTOMER_ID TRANSACTION_COUNT        SEQ  CARRYOVER
---------- ----------- ----------------- ---------- ----------
    253442       23334                 0          1          0
    253443       23334                 0          2          0
    253444       23334                 1          3          1
    253445       23334                 1          4          2
   1050646       23334                 0          5          0
   8457065       23334                 0          6          0
   9052920       23334                 2          7          2
   9333044       23334                 1          8          3
   9616743       23334                 0          9          0
   9894491       23334                 0         10          0
  10186697       23334                 0         11          0
  10490938       23334                 0         12          0
  10803986       23334                 1         13          1
  11132317       23334                 1         14          2
  11444923       23334                 0         15          0
```

It uses a very similar concept to the original solution, except by adding the check for zero or non-zero transaction_count into the partition by clause of the final sum() analytic function, we no longer need the case statement to output 0 or the sum.

Hopefully you can tell what tweaks I had to make - basically, the checks for transaction_id is null/not null had to be changed to transaction_count = 0/!= 0, plus the change of `row_number()` to `sum(transaction_count)` plus the aforementioned change to the partition by clause. I'm sure if you'd have thought about it some more, you'd have come to the same conclusion, if you haven't already! *{:-)

Comment: Thank you for an excellent answer. Assuming transaction_id is replaced with not-null transaction_count per invoice. Carryover will instead of starting with 1, start with transaction_count. Carryover is then calculated as transaction_count previous row + transaction count current row. A 0 in transaction count will as before reset the carryover to 0. is this achieveable with the use of the LAG  analytic function?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean. Please update the sample data and expected output in your question to demonstrate what you mean. On the face of it, I think you'd just need a `sum()` in place of `row_number()`, to do a cumulative sum. However, without seeing what the data looks like, as well as the expected output, it's difficult to say if that's the case.

Comment: did not give the expected results. Initial question updated above.

Comment: Think I got it:

                              Case when transaction_count <> 0 Then transaction_count + lag(transaction_count,1) over (order by customer_id,sequence) Else 0 end as carryover

Comment: no need for lag; I've updated my answer to use a cumulative sum instead of the row_number it was using before.