# How to select 1 date field with 3 tags?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm making query that select 1 datefield 3 times.

```
SELECT t1.datefield date_1, 
       t1.datefield date_2, 
       t1.datefield date_3 
FROM   table t1 
WHERE  t1.datefield BETWEEN To_date('01/07/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND To_date('31/07/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

I need date_1 between July 01 and July 31, date_2 between August 01 and 
August 31, date_3 between Septembre 01 and September 30. How can I do that?

Example:

```
SELECT t1.date_invoice date_1, 
       t1.date_invoice date_2, 
       t1.date_invoice date_3 
FROM   invoices t1 
WHERE  t1.date_invoice BETWEEN To_date('01/07/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND To_date('31/07/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')

   DATE_1       DATE_2     DATE_3        
----------   ----------- -----------
01/07/2016   14/08/2016   15/09/2016
```

But table only has one `date_invoice`.

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text!

Comment: the result i expect is
date_1 = 07/14/2016
date_2 = 08/10/2016
date_3 = 09/15/2016

but it only works with 
WHERE t1.datefield BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/07/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE('31/07/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')

When i use 
WHERE BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/07/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE('31/07/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
AND BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/08/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE('31/08/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') it gets empty data... or no data

Comment: With what table data?

Comment: i can't post that information here... in my question is the example of query that i'm using...

Comment: You don't have to post exact data; you can make up some data that is enough to demonstrate your issue. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233740/oracle-increment-value) for an example of what someone else has done to accurately describe their problem using sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you select THE SAME DATE in your query, even though you give it three different names. When you select from a single table, you get its rows, one by one. For each row in the table, you read the `date_invoice` value and you insert that one value in all three columns of your result. Then you force three conditions on this value, and the conditions are (obviously) contradicting each other, so nothing will match.

What you probably want to do is to look at three rows from your base table simultaneously - and check if the first one has a date in July, the second in August and the third in September. You may still have no results, or exactly one, or perhaps several results (if there were three invoices in July, one in August and two in September, you will get a total of 3*1*2 = 6 results).

Whenever you need to choose a row from one table AND a row from another table, that is a JOIN. In your case, you want three rows, so it's two joins. And your table is the same all three times; when you join a table to itself, that's called a "self-join" and it may sound weird the first time you see it, but it's quite common and no different from joins between different tables.

Now, perhaps you have an order_id somewhere, and you are looking only for triples of invoices for the same order_id. Then you would have a JOIN CONDITION - that the three rows all have the same order_id. Or perhaps you will first filter the base table to only look at the rows that have a given order_id in the first place.

Anyway, the way you asked the question there is no "join condition" - all invoices must be considered and matched against each other. That is called a CROSS JOIN or CARTESIAN JOIN and it is quite useful in some situations; however, often you will see such cross joins that in fact reflect an incorrect solution to a problem (such as, missing a join condition on order_id - you will get an invoice for one order in July matched to an invoice for a different order in August).

What you want with the problem the way you asked it is a repeated cross join, like this:

```
SELECT t1.datefield date_1, 
       t2.datefield date_2, 
       t3.datefield date_3 
FROM   your_table t1 CROSS JOIN your_table t2 CROSS JOIN your_table t3 
WHERE  t1.datefield BETWEEN To_date('01/07/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
                                 AND To_date('31/07/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
  AND  t2.datefield BETWEEN .... -- (dates for August)
  AND  t3.datefield BETWEEN .... -- (dates for September)
```